# Guice - Field Injection limitations

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, guice-3

Suppose that we have a class, called `Bean`, that depends on another class, called `Service`, using *Fields Injection* and **we can’t change the code of these classes**. Another class (`App`) uses a `Provider` in order to construct new instances of the Bean whenever it wants and we are free to change the code in these classes.

Since in the `Provider`'s `get()` method the new instance is created using the `new` operator it is impossible to inject the `Service` into the `Bean`, thus the `Bean` instance will be incomplete (Service field will be `null`).

One way to bypass the problem would be to inject the `Injector` in the Provider and call `injector.injectMembers()` in the `get()` method, on the new instance.

An example of the code is the following (I avoided using interfaces to make the code shorter).

```java
class Bean {
    @Inject private Service service;

    public Bean() {
    }

    public void bar() {
        this.service.foo();
    }
}

class Service {

    public void foo() {
        System.out.println("foo");
    }
}

class App {
    @Inject private Provider<Bean> beanProvider;

    public App() {
    }

    public void run() {
        this.beanProvider.get().bar();
    }
}

class BeanProvider implements Provider<Bean> {
    @Inject Injector injector;

    public Bean get() {
        Bean mybean = new Bean();
        this.injector.injectMembers(mybean);

        return mybean;
    }
}

// A simple module to bind the classes
class MyModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(Service.class);
        bind(Bean.class).toProvider(BeanProvider.class);
        bind(App.class);
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new MyModule());
    injector.getInstance(App.class).run();
}
```

The other way would be to change the Bean to use Construction Injection, but as I said let's assume that we can't do that.

I know that most people claim that injecting the `Injector` should be avoided as it breaks the whole DI philosophy since the injector should be used only at the entry point of an application and nowhere else, but since Guice offers different ways to use DI in an app, such as Field Injection, situations like the one I described may occur. Also, I've seen Field Injection to be used pretty often in several projects so cases like this can be often.

So, is there a "cleaner" way to avoid injecting the `Injector` in the problem I described?

Comment: In your example you don't actually need `BeanProvider`. Guice will create one for you. So you could just `bind(Bean.class)` with no provider and your example will work. Are there other constraints?

Comment: @condit What about the cases that Bean has narrower scope that the App? the documentation of guice (https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/InjectingProviders) advices to use a Provider in order to handle such cases. In any case, lets assume that using a Provider is mandatory. Do I still have to inject the injector?

Comment: Even then Guice will automatically inject a provider for you which should solve your scope issue (since a new `Bean` is returned per provider `get` call). The only time I find myself using `requestInjection` is for AOP.

Answer (score 4):

This seems like it should be a non-issue with your module.  It doesn't look like you should have to create a provider at all.

The bindings that you've setup in your module should cause Service to be injected into Bean wherever you need it.  So, you should just be able to replace the provider declaration in App with an injection of Bean.

```
class App {
     @Inject private Bean beanObject;

     public App() {
     }

     public void run() {
         this.beanObject.bar();
     }
}

// A simple module to bind the classes
class MyModule extends AbstractModule {
    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        //bind this to whatever you want to inject into Bean...
        bind(Service.class); 
        bind(Bean.class);
        bind(App.class);
    }
}
```

If that doesn't work for you, can you clarify what you're trying to do and why you need a provider?

Comment: thank you for your answer. The reason why I want to use Provider instead of simple injection is because in some cases the Bean class might have narrower scope than the App class (probably the names of are confusing now but the point of the question requires, for some reason, to use Provider)

Comment: Hmm... if using a provider is required, then I don't see much of a way around mucking about with the injector... (short of writing your own bit of reflective bean populator, and reimplementing the behaviour of the injector itself).

Comment: @Alex, what you inject (an object directly or a provider) does not depend at all on the kind of binding (linked, to instance, to provider, whatever). In fact, for *every* binding Guice will generate a provider, you can find it yourself in Guice source code. So unless you *really* need a provider (e.g. for classes not adapted for DI) you can use plain linked bindings.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev but what if I want a new instance of Bean every time I call the run method in App? Also, isn't it wrong to inject objects with narrower scopes? Shouldn't providers be used in such cases?

Comment: @Alex, for both of your questions the answer is: inject a provider. But it doesn't mean that you have to *bind* any provider. You can create simple linked binding and still *inject* a provider. See for yourself: https://gist.github.com/dpx-infinity/9529941. I didn't create any `toProvider()` bindings, yet I'm still able to inject a provider which creates new instances every time it is asked to.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev I agree that the provider that guice creates automatically solves this particular problem but what if for some reason I want to use a custom provider (for example I want to run some other code when new objects are Beans, or Bean requires some code in order to be created)?

Comment: Well, then you don't have much choice. Either perform `injectMembers` using an injector or inject required dependencies into your provider and pass them to the provided object manually. I'd go for the second option, if it is possible, because `injectMembers` is too implicit. But this is not really related to your original question. In that question you asked how to solve that specific problem, and it turns out that it is absolutely possible to avoid using `Injector` or even providers for that case. I think you should ask separate question about more generic case.